# Handle json using Pandas json_normalize

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, json-normalize

My goal is to convert a dictionary to a Pandas dataframe using only `json_normalize`.

**What I have:**

```
d = {'date': '20-NOV-2021', 'sector': {'South': 8, 'Est': 9, 'North': 12, 'Ouest': 9}}
pd.json_normalize(d)

       date  sector.South  sector.Est  sector.North  sector.Ouest
20-NOV-2021             8           9            12             9
```

**What I'm looking for:**

```
sector   value          date
South    8       20-NOV-2021
Est      9       20-NOV-2021
North    12      20-NOV-2021
Ouest    9       20-NOV-2021
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to convert your `sector` data into a slightly different format:

```py
d['sector'] = [{'sector': k, 'value': v} for k, v in dd['sector'].items()]
df = pd.json_normalize(d, "sector", "date")
```

Output:

```py
>>> df
  sector  value         date
0  South      8  20-NOV-2021
1    Est      9  20-NOV-2021
2  North     12  20-NOV-2021
3  Ouest      9  20-NOV-2021
```